# Can my wizard conjure a bedroll so that I don’t have to carry a sleeping mat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items, wizard

Is there a spell I can use to create a bedroll each night? A magic item would be suitable as well. The spell should be of a low level, i.e. 1 or 2.

Answer (score 14):

There aren't many things that fit your criteria--either a low-level spell that creates a comfy thing to sleep on *or* a magic item that makes a comfy thing to sleep on that's appropriate for a level 4 character. Nonetheless, here's

## One Spell and Two Items

- The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *Leomund's tiny igloo* [conj] (*Fr* 101) for 2 hours/level creates an igloo for Medium you and 3 Medium friends. Its walls have hardness 0 and 3 hp per caster level, it withstands up to (but *not* including) hurricane winds, and its magically heated. It's very cool.<sup>1</sup>
- The slotless item *survival pouch* (*MIC* 187-8) (3,300 gp; 5 lbs.) grants the possessor the ability as a standard action 5/day to pull from it a variety of things, including a tent and 2 bedrolls as but 1 of its 5 uses per day. Other items include a lit campfire and a *summoned*-like decked-out mule (although it won't fight for you).
- The slotless item *Heward's fortifying bedroll* (*CM* 132-3) (3,000 gp; 2 lbs.) grants the user the ability to get 8 hours rest in just 1 hour.

Both items are expensive for a lone level 4 character, but splitting the cost among party members makes either more palatable. The *pouch* is extremely versatile, and if your party's permanently camping it should provide everything your party needs in a 5 lb. package. And while it's a little gross taking shifts sleeping in the same *fortifying bedroll*, it's *only* an hour--just use the spell *prestidigitation* afterward to clean off leftover barbarian lice.<sup>2</sup> The advantage of shorter watches with more people on them is huge.

---

1. Sorry.
2. The lice are *from* the barbarian *not* actual barbarians.

Comment: Oh good. I don't think I could handle *uncivilized* lice again. The drinking, the carousing, the tiny axes... you really can't get any sleep that way. On the plus side, they do hunt and kill other lesser vermin.

Answer (score 11):

### Wizard Tricks

1. Have a minion.  Carrying things is for dweebs - the wizard on the go has a little skeleton buddy (Necromancer alternate class feature from UA), a hired minion, or a Fighter to lug his stuff for him.
2. Tenser's Floating Disk, or a Talisman of the Disk, can handle your 'carrying stuff' problem, admittedly though only for a couple of hours at low levels.
3. *Prestidigitation*, the wonder-cantrip, can clean things and create a few pounds of soft material.  Grab some grass or dirt, clean it until it's soft, and then manifest a pillow.
4. Spell Research!  Summon Bedroll sounds like a 1st or 2nd level spell to me, and custom spell research is Core!  (DM Fiat, though)
5. *Endure Elements* makes wrapping yourself up in your fancy cloak (all wizards have fancy cloaks) and sleeping the night much less of a hassle!

At higher levels, a *portable hole* with a bedroom-cum-lab slotted into it is fine diddly dandy, as is a Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion.  But yeah, at lower levels, you're basically gonna have to rough it.  There's not even an easy magical way to sling a hammock, until you start hitting the mid-ranges where it's easier just to teleport home.

Comment: Careful with that portable hole! You may have to leave your handy haversack outside.

Comment: I have a problem with summon bedroll.  Powerwise it's obviously a weak 1st level spell--but 1st level spells are normally no more than 1 hr/level.

Comment: *Endure Elements* is a 24hr Duration 1st-Level spell.  There is no rule about spell duration vs spell level, in practice or anywhere in the books.

Answer (score 7):

*Leomund's Secure Shelter* will do you one better, by conjuring a whole cottage. Not a very large cottage, mind you (that's what *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion* is for), but it'll get the job done, and it comes with basic furnishings. The main drawback is that it's a fourth-level spell.

If you're willing to be a bit more flexible, you could also get by with *Leomund's Tiny Hut*. It's only 3rd level, and it actually provides better protection from the elements: the *Shelter* has to be heated and cooled like any ordinary house would, while the *Hut* does not. On the other hand, the *Hut* doesn't come furnished, so you'd still need to either bring a bedroll or forage for something a little softer than the ground. It also won't protect you from attacks like the *Shelter* can. But if your main concern is making camping as little work as possible, it's probably a better option.

One of my DMs recently let me research the process of making an "instant yurt" that could set itself up on demand, and pack itself up into a small pouch for easy portability: sort of like a *folding boat* except with a large, comfortable tent. I used *Leomund's Tiny Hut* as the principal spell in the process. It actually worked out quite well.

Answer (score 5):

Some spells to summon items:

- [Drawmij's Instant Summons](http://dndtools.eu/spells/players-handbook-v35--6/drawmijs-instant-summons--2389/)
- [Instant Summons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/instantSummons.htm)

A conjuration spells to *make* the item:

- [Minor Creation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/minorCreation.htm)

Some other good standbys:

- [Secure Shelter](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/secureShelter.htm)
- [Mage's Magnificent Mansion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm)

Finally, you can get into epic spells, and use the [conjure spell seed](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/seeds/conjure.htm)

You could finally try and convince the DM to allow you to *make* a spell for specifically summoning/conjuring a bedroll.

Sadly, it looks like conjuring useful items like this just isn't accessible to low-level wizards.

Answer (score 3):

You say you need a sleeping mat? Well, you'd have to wake up thrice to get your 9 hours of sleep (the amount you've stated in your comment), but as *a very non-RAW solution*, I'd say casting [**Mage Armor**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mageArmor.htm) could be a solution. :D

It's a first level spell, so you can cast it. The rules say it's a tangible field of force, so it would keep you away from both the ground and minor creatures. Its description also states that it entails no speed reduction and no armor penalty at all - so it's probably not too tough either. And it keeps you protected as well. All you have to do, again, is to renew it thrice during the night. And waste three good spells... (I dare suppose your wizard has some bonus spells?)

Note: Don't take this answer too seriously, please. (Even though it could work. At least in my campaigns, for a mage foolish enough to do this.) :D

Comment: Note that the problem with recasting only occurs if my wizard notices that the mage armor has worn off and wakes up from it anyhow. My wizard therefore doesn’t need an alarm clock to use this trick, and, if he sleeps peacefully, will need to cast the spell only once to fall asleep. So (+1).